# RabbitMQ IModel.Dispose hangs

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

For some reason this started happening. Didn't yesterday. My client hangs after `channel.BasicPublish` returns in `channel.Dispose`. My connection is *not* bad, i.e. it's in open state and app is not being shutdown as suggested in https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rabbitmq-discuss/5nzeEqI5qxw. Both ways behave the same:

```
using (var channel = _connection.CreateModel()) {
  //use channel here
}
```

and

```
var channel = _connection.CreateModel()
//use channel here
channel.Dispose();
```

Comment: What version of the RabbitMQ server and client are you seeing this problem on? We think we had a similar problem and fixed it by reverting out client to 3.4.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have bug 25255 on this issue - [link](http://markmail.org/message/tqyiezrmixagtwa4).

For now try using a timeout around this call.

```
private void DisconnectWithTimeout(IConnection connection, int timeoutMillis)
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => connection.Dispose());

    if (!task.Wait(timeoutMillis))
    {
        //timeout
        throw new TimeoutException("Timeout on connection.Dispose()");
    }
}
```

Comment: The bug is happening for me with the latest.